# Fetch all the rows with same column number in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a modal button associated with each student on a table. When I press the button I want to be able to fetch all results associated with the admission_num from another table. The code I have is below.

[image]

Here is my controller code

```
public function view_student_result($id)
{

    $user= User::where('admission_num', $id)->get();
    
    $resultdata = juniorResults::where('admission_num', $id)->get();



    return view('backend.student_result_view', compact('resultdata', 'user'));
}
```

Here is my route

```
Route::get('view-student-result/{id}', [viewResultController::class, 'view_student_result'])->name('view_student_result');
```

Here is the button that links to the view result page

```
  <a href="{{ route('view_student_result', $studentDatas->admission_num) }}"><i class="fas fa-print"></i></a>
```

When I used get(), I got this error **Property [admission_num] does not exist on this collection instance.** But when I use first() instead of get() the code was able to fetch just one result. below is the dd(collection)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to look up all entries having a specific number or just all entries that have duplicates in this row?

Comment: you are searching for `id` with `find` not any other column (there will only be 1 record with a particular id), even if you switched the model's primary key to that field you want to search against it will still only return 1 record ... if you want to search by a column use a `where` statement and `get` to retrieve all the matching results instead of 1

Comment: Thank you for your response, I want to fetch all entries (rows) with the same admission number.

Comment: Use `juniorResults::where('Admission_Num',$id)->get();` syntax

Comment: Thank you, I got this error "Property [Admission_Num] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: I have reframed the question please check. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all rows you dont have to use `first()`. Instead of first what you returns only the first userobject you have to use all() or get.
`$user= User::where('admission_num', $id)->get();`

**small note**
You screenshot from you database table admission_num is upper case the first letter. And in your eloquent query you have lower case.

Comment: Thanks for your response, when I use `$user= User::where('admission_num', $id)->get();` I got this response, **Property [admission_num] does not exist on this collection instance.** Also for the screenshot, I have corrected the column name to **admission_num**

Comment: You welcome! That sounds good! It means that `admission_num`not exists in your collection. Try `Admission_num` with (upper case first letter). see my note in my answer... Change it in your controller and in your view too.

Comment: Thank you, I have adjusted the column name on the database to match that in my controller but I keep getting the error **Property [admission_num] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Comment: @Samuel can you make `dd(yourCollection)` and share it please

Comment: This is what I got when I dd(yourCollection). `^ Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1488 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => App\Models\juniorResults {#1490 ▶}
    1 => App\Models\juniorResults {#1491 ▶}
    2 => App\Models\juniorResults {#1492 ▶}
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}` **Do note that when I extended each item of the array, I got the results from the database**

Comment: please check the edited question for a screenshot of the dd.

Comment: @Samuel Ok. That looks good! and i think the problem occurs becasue you try to access `admission_num` directly from the collection. But you need iterate first. for example in your blade. like that: `@foreach( $studentDatas as $data) {{ $data->admission_num }} @endforeach`

Comment: thanks so much, I just got the problem solved. All these while I had my foreach loop inside <ttable> tag. It worked perfectly after I brought it out. Thanks for your wonderful contributions.

Answer (score 1):

To get all students with a specific `Admission_num`, you can use this statement:

```php
$resultdata = juniorResults::where('Admission_num', 12345)->get();
```

Small hint: Instead of writing your url by hand, it is safer to use the name of your route:

```php
<a href="{{ route('view_student_result', $studentDatas['id']) }}"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this but I got this error "Property [Admission_Num] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: Can you show us the migration file of this table? Should be located in `/database/migration/xx-xx-xx-create_junior_results_table` or something like that

Comment: `public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('junior_results', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('Subject');
            $table->string('Score');
            $table->string('Grade');
            $table->string('Admission_Num');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }`

Comment: Seems fine to me, what do you get when you `dump(juniorResults::first())` ? Under `attributes` , does the object contain your Admission_Num value?

Comment: I think there might be an issue somewhere in the code. I will update you as soon as possible.

Comment: When I use `$resultdata = juniorResults::where('Admission_Num', $id)->first();` I still get a single data.

Comment: Yes thats for sure, but when you look at the data you get, this object, does it contain the attribute `Admission_Num` ?

Comment: Yes I have Admission_Num

Comment: Be aware that after you executed `$result = juniorResults::where('Admission_Num', $id)->get()` you receive a Collection instance which you have to iterate over like this: `foreach($result as $juniorResult) { echo($juniorResult->Admission_Num)`

Comment: `$resultdata = juniorResults::where('Admission_Num', $id)->get();` returns this error **Property [Subject] does not exist on this collection instance.**

Comment: Are you really sure that you are accessing the attributes of the single objects? I think you are doing this: `$resultdata->Admission_Num` . That will not work. `$resultdata` is a collection and has no attributes like that.

Comment: I have reframed the question with a little code adjustment. Please check, thanks!